How to detect the hibernation phase for suspend-then-hibernate without env variable?
On Ubuntu, it's possible to run a script before and after a laptop is suspended by adding a script to /lib/systemd/system-sleep. When using the suspend-then-hibernate command, officially it's possible for these scripts to know whether the laptop is about to begin the suspend phase or move into the hibernation phase by checking the SYSTEMD_SLEEP_ACTION environment variable.
However, this was only the case after a 2021 update to systemd. Before that, the scripts in system-sleep would still be invoked for both phases, but with the same arguments i.e. pre suspend-then-hibernate for both the start of suspend as well as the start of hibernation. This is noted here and this GitHub issue was the reason why the SYSTEMD_SLEEP_ACTION environment variable was added.
Unfortunately I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, which is packaged with an older version of systemd that doesn't have this environment variable yet. From what I read, it's risky and a massive headache to update systemd. I want to use suspend-then-hibernate, but because my laptop has an Nvidia GPU, I have to make sure the laptop runs /usr/bin/nvidia-sleep.sh "hibernate" right before entering hibernation. Without SYSTEMD_SLEEP_ACTION, I would need a workaround to get the information about whether my script in system-sleep is being called before suspension or before hibernation.
What are some alternative methods I can use to figure out that my computer is about to enter the hibernation phase of suspend-then-hibernate? One hack I thought of is to check how much time has passed between post suspend-then-hibernate and pre suspend-then-hibernate, if the time between these is less than 5 seconds I treat the event as a hibernation. This is of course not the most elegant or reliable strategy. If I make the computer sleep within 5 seconds of waking, my script will think the computer is about to hibernate. But I can't be certain how short the delay will be when suspend-then-hibernate actually wants to hibernate my computer.
Are there other methods, possibly still hacky or nonportable but more reliable, that I can use to replace my 5 seconds check?

Asking for "strategies" and "hacks" is likely to attract close votes because this is asking for opinions and indicates you do not have a specific question. Instead, focus on a specific question, and focus on this in the post title and question body.
